# How to find the attempted URL when site user gets 404 error with php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

When a user attempts to go to an invalid link on my page and is forwarded to a 404 page, is there a way to see what was the attempted url.

Example: If user types "example.com/stary" instead of "example.com/start"; how can I retrieve the attempted url ("example.com/stary") using php.

Comment: maybe by looking inside `$_SERVER` for the requested page, inside your custom 404 page, and checking http status code. If it's 404, you can assume the requested page does not exist ; you will need to define an ErrorDocument inside .htaccess

Comment: From where user is forwarded to 404?? from .htaccess or from index.php or you are not handling this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess rule

if index.php is your main file you can manage all request GET/POST...

```
if you get the URL GET start you may take action action can define in index.php
sample .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you just check

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']
```

For better under standing , use print_r (php function ) on index.php file to check other fields in this variable.

```
print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```